# Windows forms container : Panel, how to access an element at a particular index?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wish to check if a checkbox is checked every two element in my panel and I can't find any property or method that would allow that in the manual of Panel on MSDN site.

I know I can check each element like that :

```
   foreach (CheckBox currentCheck in this.panel_Schedule.Controls)
        {
            if (currentCheck.Checked)
            {
                nbScheduleModesChecked++;
            }
        }
```

but the problem here is that if an element is different than a checkbox is in the panel an error occure saying it can't convert the element to a checkbox.

**Edit** :

To add a precision about my case, I have a panel with several CheckBox each followed by a NumericUpDown. I wish to be able to check if a checkbox is checked to :

- count the total of checked checkbox **(this is already answered)**.
- change the state of the NumericUpDown to hide whether the checkbox above is checked or not.
- change the state of a checkbox to checked or unchecked according to other checkbox which aren't in the panel.

I hope this will help you to understand my problem better.

**Edit 2**:

Here is an exemple of the best kind of answer i'm hoping for

```
   for (int i;i < panel_Schedule.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
           if (panel_Schedule.__what i wish to know__[i].getType() == CheckBox)
           {
              if (panel_Schedule.__what i wish to know__[i].checked)
              {
                  //Do something like uncheck or make NumericUpDown appear
              }
           }
        }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney, I think he means that every other element in his panel (visually, perhaps?) is a `CheckBox`, and for each checked `CheckBox` he wants to increment his count.  Sounds like your suggestion should work nicely, and he wouldn't even have to count them himself, just use `Count`.

Comment: Just don't lose the references to these controls.  It becomes simple when you create a UserControl instead of a Panel, now you can give these controls a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem thanks to the answer above.
What I searched for was :

```
    panel_Schedule.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ElementAt<CheckBox>(index)
```

in my code it looks like this :

```
    for (int index = 0; index < panel_Schedule.Controls.Count / 2; index++)
        {
            CheckBox currentCheck = panel_Schedule.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ElementAt<CheckBox>(index);
            if (currentCheck.Checked)
            {
                panel_Schedule.Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>().ElementAt<NumericUpDown>(index).Visible = true;
                nbScheduleModesChecked++;
            }
            else
            {
                panel_Schedule.Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>().ElementAt<NumericUpDown>(index).Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Thank you to all those who contributed to answer me.

Answer (score 1):

This will grab the `CheckBox` controls in your `Panel`, and return a total of those that are checked:

```
int totalChecked = panel_Schedule.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(x => x.Checked);
```

Comment: This could have been the solution, the problem with that is I can't say if a particular checkbox is checked in the panel then do something with another particular element in the panel. In my case I want to be able to hide a numericUpdown (there is one after each checkbox) when a checkbox is not checked and the contrary if it's checked.

Comment: I'm sorry that I was not specific enough, I updated my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i have no idea about how to subscribe to an event. So if you could tell me how or redirect me to a tutorial please.

Comment: After I read again your answer I see that this is not the answer which I seek. As I say in the title I want to be able to access to an element (checkbox) at a particular index in a way similar to access a particular index in an int array by doing tab[i] (i is the index). I have difficulties to explain what I want it seems but tell me if you want a better exemple.